# Serialize Javascript array as PHP string for Laravel cache

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, serialization, redis

I need to save a PHP array as serialized data suitable for Laravel's cache system. My code so far using [node-php-serialization](https://github.com/joesonw/node-php-serialization) is:

```
var serialize=require("php-serialization").serialize;
var sernew = serialize(result, "string");
```

This produces:

```
"s:11:"bob,dave,mark";"
```

But this doesn't work in Laravel's cache. I need:

```
"s:27:\"[\"bob\",\"dave\",\"mark\"]\";"
```

Can this package do this? Does anyone know of a way it can be formatted as above?

Many thanks.

Additional details:

The array to be inserted comes from the cache, is converted to Javascript array, altered, then converted back to the cache string:

```
rediscache.get(key, function (err, result) {
      result = unserialize(result);
      result = JSON.parse(result);

      for(var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
          if(result[i] === username) {
             result.splice(i, 1);
          }
      }

      var sernew = serialize(result, "string");

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you want - `"s:27:\"[\"bob\",\"dave\",\"mark\"]\";"` - is a JSON string `["bob","dave","mark"]`.

What you insert back to serialize is just a string. In this exact case, doing this will work:

```
var sernew = serialize(JSON.stringify(("bob,dave,mark").split(",")), "string");
```

But it might not work in all cases if you're not just having a simple array.

Can you show the full path of what are you doing with the string. Something might be incorrectly done.

Comment: I've added some additional details. I'll look into converting the array back to JSON...

Comment: The result that you get after doing the splicing is an array. You should be turning that array back to a JSON string with JSON.stringify() as I've mentioned and only then serializing. `var sernew = serialize(JSON.parse(result), "string");`